# Nestedkey with mixin pino-logger

Tags: javascript, typescript, logging, datadog, pinojs

I have this logger model:

```
  LoggerModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: (configService: ConfigService<AppConfig, true>) => ({
    pinoHttp: {
      level: configService.get('logger.level', { infer: true }),
      autoLogging: false,
      name: 'someName',
      messageKey: 'message', // take advantage Datadog's default facet
      mixin(): Record<string, unknown> {
        return {
          dd: { ...getDatadogMixin(tracer) },
        };
      },
      nestedKey: 'metadata',
      reqCustomProps(req) {
        return {
          executionId: req.headers[EXECUTION_ID],
        };
      },
    },
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
}),
```

I know that as of pino 7.x, when the mixin is used with the `nestedKey` option, the object returned from the mixin method will also be nested.

I'm trying to revert that, which means that I want the object that returning from the mixin method would still be at the root.

```
{"level":30,"time":1591195061437,"pid":16012,"hostname":"x", dd: {<dd-tracing-object>}, "metadata": 
{"executionId":"12345"},"msg":"Message 1"}
```

tnx.

Answer (score 0):

The only option I found with `pino` was to remove the option `nestedKey` and use the optional function `formatters.log` to wrap the log object into your `nestedKey` and provide the details under `getDatadogMixin()`.
But beware this method would require you to review other `pino` config you could have set (e.g. `serializers` or `redact`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by writing a custom logMethod that hoists the metadata e.g.

```
const hooks = {
  logMethod (inputArgs, method, level) {
    const mappedInputArgs = inputArgs.map((arg) => {
      return arg instanceof Object ? { metadata: arg } : arg;
    });
    return method.apply(this, mappedInputArgs)
  }
}

const logger = pino({
  hooks,
  mixin(_, level) {
    return { 'severity': pino.levels.labels[level] }
  },
});

logger.info({ foo: 'bar' }, 'Hello');
```

Output

```
{"level":30,"time":1710514951366,"pid":83790,"severity":"info","metadata":{"foo":"bar"},"msg":"Hello"}
```

Comment: If my previous suggesting of using the logMethod doesn't work well in your context, you might also try specifying a formatter. These can change the shape of the log object